# Mouse wheel in python curses

Tags: python, mousewheel, curses

Does anyone know if it is possible to process the mouse wheel movements in curses? I suppose they should be the same as the arrow keys. An example would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd guess it's system- and terminal-dependent. I wrote the following -- it just captures mouse states and prints them to the screen. I was able to receive mouse scroll events in Mac OSX using xterm. (Scrolling up registered as button 4 for me; down as button 2 -- but it didn't work using the native Terminal app.)

As will become clear if you look over this code, you have to use `scr.getch()` first, and test if it returns `curses.KEY_MOUSE`. If so, you can then call [`curses.getmouse()`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.getmouse), which returns a tuple containing a device id, coordinates, and a state flag.

```
import curses
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def open_screen():
    scr = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    scr.keypad(1)
    try:
        yield scr
    finally:
        curses.nocbreak()
        scr.keypad(0)
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()

curses_mouse_states = {
    curses.BUTTON1_PRESSED: 'Button 1 Pressed', 
    curses.BUTTON1_RELEASED: 'Button 1 Released', 
    curses.BUTTON1_CLICKED: 'Button 1 Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON1_DOUBLE_CLICKED: 'Button 1 Double-Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON1_TRIPLE_CLICKED: 'Button 1 Triple-Clicked',

    curses.BUTTON2_PRESSED: 'Button 2 Pressed', 
    curses.BUTTON2_RELEASED: 'Button 2 Released', 
    curses.BUTTON2_CLICKED: 'Button 2 Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON2_DOUBLE_CLICKED: 'Button 2 Double-Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON2_TRIPLE_CLICKED: 'Button 2 Triple-Clicked',

    curses.BUTTON3_PRESSED: 'Button 3 Pressed', 
    curses.BUTTON3_RELEASED: 'Button 3 Released', 
    curses.BUTTON3_CLICKED: 'Button 3 Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON3_DOUBLE_CLICKED: 'Button 3 Double-Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON3_TRIPLE_CLICKED: 'Button 3 Triple-Clicked',

    curses.BUTTON4_PRESSED: 'Button 4 Pressed', 
    curses.BUTTON4_RELEASED: 'Button 4 Released', 
    curses.BUTTON4_CLICKED: 'Button 4 Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON4_DOUBLE_CLICKED: 'Button 4 Double-Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON4_TRIPLE_CLICKED: 'Button 4 Triple-Clicked',

    curses.BUTTON_SHIFT: 'Button Shift', 
    curses.BUTTON_CTRL: 'Button Ctrl', 
    curses.BUTTON_ALT: 'Button Alt'
}

with open_screen() as scr:
    curses.mousemask(-1)
    while True:
        c = scr.getch()
        if c == curses.KEY_MOUSE:
            mouse_state = curses.getmouse()[4]
            states = '; '.join(state_string for state, state_string 
                               in curses_mouse_states.viewitems() 
                               if mouse_state & state)
            scr.addstr(0, 0, states)
            scr.clrtoeol()
            scr.refresh()
        elif c == ord('q'):
            break
```