# Detect mouse side button events in Python

Tags: python, gtk, mouse, mouseevent

I am searching for a way to get the events when clicking the 'Back' and 'Forward' buttons on the side of a normal mouse.

This function can be found in Firefox (for going back/forward) and Sublime Text 2 (for switching between tabs).

I know that there is a Windows program set that is called pyHook, but I would like to have something for Python in Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this for a GUI?  If so, what framework are you using?

Comment: Yes, I am programming a little GUI that displays buttons and some text. I am using Python + GTK on Ubuntu. I want that when the user clicks these side buttons, the previous or next page builds up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the example code in the answer to this question might be useful to you: [Mouse wheel in python curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893034/mouse-wheel-in-python-curses)